# setAlarmClock() strange behavior on samsung device (lollipop)

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

i want to launch an alarm with the setAlarmClock method of the AlarmManager class, but this doesn't work, i have the icon which appears in the status bar and disappears when it is the time's alarm but my broadcast receiver doesn't fire at all.

My code is like this :

```
   if(versionOfAndroid >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

       AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
       alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, pendingIntent);
   }
```

and my broadcast receiver like this:

```
 private class SelfWakeUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WAKE_UP_ALARM)) {



            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, WakeUpActivity.class);
            intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
            context.startActivity(intent1);

      }
```

I don't understand, the icon appears and disappear at the time of the alarm, but nothing else happens. this app works fine on kitkat on other device than samsung with their smart manager...

My pendingIntent is like that:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, numeroAlarm, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

and my Intent like that in onCreate() method:

```
 broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, SelfWakeUpReceiver.class);
 broadcastIntent.setAction(ACTION_WAKE_UP_ALARM);
```

I register the receiver like that:

```
    intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(WakeUpActivity.ACTION_STOP_ALARM);
    intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_WAKE_UP_ALARM);

    registerReceiver(mSelfWakeUpReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Comment: How are you creating `pendingIntent`? Have you added any logging to see if you are getting control but not going into your `if` block? Are there any interesting LogCat messages at the point in time when the alarm clock event occurs?

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your help, i editing my post. Yes i am getting control in my if{} statement ( i remove my log.i(...) in if{} statement).When i initiate my alarm, i have this infos in Logcat:  Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@843990e time:122065797 . But nothing else, when alarm is triggered, only the icon in the status bar disappears.

Comment: "Yes i am getting control in my if{} statement" -- I now see that you have two `if` statements. I was referring to the one in the `SelfWakeUpReceiver`. Are you getting control there? If yes, then the problem is that the device does not want to start your activity. If no, then the problem is that the device does not want to send the broadcast, or your `PendingIntent` is somehow getting cancelled.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh Ok, no i am not getting control in my if{}  statement in my receiver... I don't understand why ? i tested in my Motorola device (kitkat) and it doesn't work too, so my receiver is the problem. i register my receiver like that in onCreate() method (see edit)

Comment: I have never tried `setAlarmClock()` with a receiver registered via `registerReceiver()`. That is unlikely to work well, as your process may be terminated in between calling `setAlarmClock()` and the time when the event occurs. I suggest that you register that receiver in the manifest.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, but if i register my receiver in the manifest, i need to make my Class static.But i need to have acces to my instance variable in my receiver, so how i can do this (static receiver and have acces to my receiver), i will to try with static receiver. Thanks you very much for your invaluable help

Comment: Again, your entire process may go away between `setAlarmClock()` and when the time comes for the event. Hence, there is no instance variable. You need to persist your data, so that it will be around when the event occurs. If you want to use something like a static field as a cache (taking care to avoid memory leaks), that's fine, but that's an optimization. `setAlarmClock()` is for events hours or days in the future; no app lives that long.

Comment: @CommonsWare I understand better now, thnaks you.

Answer (score 0):

i tried to change my broadcastreceiver as suggested by @CommonsWare and it works perfectly.So the problem was my dynamically registered receiver, i registered my receiver in the manifest file and its OK.

the problem was not the samsung device manager or setAlarmClock() method but the receiver and its registration.In the manifest, it works well.